# Cannot install kinetic (unmet dependencies)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, package, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have an installation problem. By running "sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop" on a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial)
i have the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

ros-kinetic-desktop : 

Depends: ros-kinetic-common-tutorials but it is not going to be installed

   Depends: ros-kinetic-geometry-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: ros-kinetic-robot but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: ros-kinetic-visualization-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: ros-kinetic-viz but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what can i do?
thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244974/cannot-install-kinetic-(unmet-dependencies)/) by [aerydna](https://answers.ros.org/users/27607/aerydna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-10-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) on 2016-10-20**:
same problem here. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem and I managed to solve it by correctly installing `restricted`, `universe`, and `multiverse` repositories as it is described in [link](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu).

My problem was that the packages seemed to be installed however, they were not able to find some of their packages. I solved that problem by changing the `Download From` to `Main Server` in Ubuntu's `software and update`.

I also explained my solution here: [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/243920/how-to-install-ros-kinetic-ubuntu-1604/?answer=265528#post-id-265528)

---

Originally posted by [tekin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26271/tekin/) with karma: 86 on 2017-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar (probably the same) problem. To check if you problem is similar to mine, try installing this package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding
```

If apt-get complains about unmet dependency **libpyside2-dev**, than it is actually the same problem.

The solution for me was to remove a bunch of packages and install them again:

libpyside2-dev, libshiboken2-dev, pyqt5-dev, python-pyqt5, python-pyqt5.qtsvg, python-pyside2, python-sip-dev, shiboken2, qtbase5-dev, qt5-qmake and **all the packages starting with libqt5**.

In short, the problem was probably related to a newer version of qt5 being installed on my system.
I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2016-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sindhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28472/sindhu/) on 2016-11-08**:
how to remove and reinstall those packages? Please explain in detail

**Comment by [jdmartin86](https://answers.ros.org/users/23737/jdmartin86/) on 2016-12-19**:
I verified the unmet dependency, and this solution still did not't help me.

**Comment by [merosss](https://answers.ros.org/users/14411/merosss/) on 2018-07-11**:
Thanks this was the solution for me! qt5 was breaking ros installation

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2018-10-10**:
I installed that qt binding but I still cannot install the full desktop ros.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, guys,
I've solved the same problem by adding  *deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe* to the file  /etc/apt/sources.list, and run the command  *sudo apt-get update*, then install the kinetic by run *sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full*, everything went smoothly.
You guys can visit the link https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/python-qt-binding/download for more detail.
Davide Faconti  is right, the problem is the lack of *python-qt-binding* in the system or something goes with the packages.

---

Originally posted by [iamfucked](https://answers.ros.org/users/32834/iamfucked/) with karma: 11 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2018-10-10**:
Nope, this did not work for me.

**Comment by [jleng](https://answers.ros.org/users/50523/jleng/) on 2020-10-22**:
This worked for me like a charm. I added the stuff into sources.list and thanks for reminding me that I need to run sudo apt-get update for it to take effect!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add following package sources to /etc/apt/sources.list.

```
deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Now, follow these steps from 1.2  in this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list)

---

Originally posted by [vikas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34075/vikas/) with karma: 31 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruderik](https://answers.ros.org/users/12146/ruderik/) on 2018-03-15**:
this worked for me!

**Comment by [Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37954/fan/) on 2019-10-30**:
after this, I did *sudo apt-get update*, then run *sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop*, and it worked